# Using VBA to assemble a list to pass to a function expecting a ParamArray

Tags: vba, function, parameters, paramarray

In a question regarding [VBA: Passing multiple values to Instr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881040/vba-passing-multiple-values-to-instr) John Coleman posted a 'Contains' function that accepts multiple search strings that are then fed into Instr to check, this was great for me and works well. However, it required writing a list of the search strings at design time (as far as I can tell), and I wanted to be able to create dynamic lists of search strings gathered from various places on the speadsheet. So in his function I would call it like this;

```
If Contains(StringToSearch, "Alan", "Betty", "Arthur", True)
```

and I wanted to be able to call it more like this;

```
If Contains(StringToSearch, Range("B1:B3"), True)
```

I then tried to see if I could assemble my entries dynamically and then pass the result to his function but could not do that like this using 2 different methods;

```
Dim varClasses() As Variant          (Method 1)
Dim strClasses() As String           (Method 2)
For i = 0 To n
  strClasses(i) = Range("C5").Offset(0, i).Value '(Method 1)
  varClasses(i) = Range("C5").Offset(0, i).Value '(Method 2)
Next i
If Contains(sEntry, strClasses, True) Then       '(Method 1)
If Contains(sEntry, varClasses, True) Then       '(Method 2)
  MsgBox "Found"
End If
```

So I want to be able to create a list of search terms that will be accepted by the function to do the multiple word searches. Thanks for reading.

Comment: On top of the methods listed in the duplicate question, if your main use case is passing an existing array, just remove the `ParamArray` keyword from the function definition. And when you do need to pass a design-time array to such function, pass `Array("Alan", "Betty", "Arthur")`.

Comment: Thanks I have read and will re read. My point was I don't want to pass a hard coded set of search terms - I want to form them up dynamically and then pass that to the function  - IE not like Array("Alan", "Betty", "Arthur") but like Array = Range("B1:B3).

Comment: Then just remove `ParamArray`.

Comment: You would benefit by reading up on Scripting.Dictionary object to collect your strings and the  the .Items method of the Scripting.Dictionary to provide a list of strings to your function.